# Custom creation of related SubFactory using factory_boy

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, faker, factory-boy

Assume I have the following classes:

```py
@dataclass
class Image:
    array: np.ndarray


@dataclass
class Label:
    array: np.ndarray


@dataclass
class Sample:
    image: Image
    label: Label
```

with the following `factory_boy` factories:

```py
class ImageFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Image

    class Params:
        shape = (64, 64)

    array = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: np.random.random(o.shape))


class LabelFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Label

    class Params:
        shape = (64, 64)

    array = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: np.random.randint(0, 2, o.shape))
```

Now, the `SampleFactory` is not as straightforward. I need to create an `Image` and `Label` that are related. Since this:

```py
class SampleFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample

    image = factory.SubFactory(ImageFactory)
    label = factory.SubFactory(LabelFactory)
```

generates independent `Image` and `Label` classes. Assume I have a `random_sample` function that generates the **arrays** used by classes `Image` and `Label`. How could I use this in the `SampleFactory`? Furthermore, assume now the `SampleFactory` has a `Param` shape, used in the `random_sample` i.e. `random_sample(shape)` how would the implementation on the `SampleFactory` be?

**Update 1**

Seems this may be used, not sure if it's the best way:

```py
class SampleFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample

    class Params:
        shape = (32, 32)

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        params = {k: v.value for k, v in cls._meta.parameters.items()}
        image_array, label_array = random_sample(**params)
        image = Image(array=image_array)
        label = Label(array=label_array)

        return Sample(image=image, label=label)
```

**Update 2**

Using `exclude` in the `Meta` is a better option since it won't affect subclassing:

```py
class SampleFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        exclude = ("data",)

    class Params:
        shape = (32, 32)

    data = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: random_sample(o.shape))
    image = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: Image(o.data[0]))
    label = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: Label(o.data[1]))
```